# sum different outputs of a function with repetition

Tags: python, sum, iterable

I would like to determine the probability of finding, a palindrome of length 3, 4 and 5, for which I must add the palindromes, the problem that I have that at the moment of making the sum tells me that they are not interable data, and tried with list, for loop and I have not been successful.

```
    import random
    import re

    def repetition():
        print('repetition','palindrome3','palindrome4','palindrome5')
        for e in range(20):
            seq=''.join(random.choice('abcdg')for i in range(35+1))
            #print(seq)
            secuencia=seq

            num3 = '(?=(.{%d}))' %3
            length3 = re.findall(num3,secuencia)
            palindrome3 = list(filter(lambda x: (x == "".join(reversed(x))),length3)) 
    
            num4 = '(?=(.{%d}))' %4
            length4 = re.findall(num4,secuencia)
            palindrome4 = list(filter(lambda x: (x == "".join(reversed(x))),length4)) 
         
            num5 = '(?=(.{%d}))' %5
            length5 = re.findall(num5,secuencia)
            palindrome5 = list(filter(lambda x: (x == "".join(reversed(x))),length5)) 
  
            print(e+1,len(palindrome3),len(palindrome4),len(palindrome5))

    print(sum(len(palindrome3)))

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: When I run the code, there is no error. Just a general note: You generate random data and never print it, just the results. How (except when getting an error) do you assess whether the result is indeed correct? I'd suggest at least using `random.seed(0)` so the data is random but reproducible.

Comment: Also note that the regex will not capture overlapping matches, e.g. for `seq = "aabbbcc..."` you would check `aab`, `bbc`, ... but miss the palindrome `bbb`. Maybe just use string slicing instead? E.g. `palindrome3 = [s for s in (seq[i:i+3] for i in range(len(seq)-2)) if s == s[::-1]]`